# How to find most frequent values per batch using "rolling(window)"?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to apply a rolling window function to `y_train` DataFrame:

`y_train` is a single column:

```
0
0
1
..
2
0
3
0
```

Unique values in `y_train`:

```
np.unique(y_train.values)

> array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

When I apply this code, I get float values in `y_train`:

```
window = 20
y_train = y_train.rolling(window).median().dropna()
```

New unique values in `y_train`:

```
np.unique(y_train.values)

> array([0. , 0.5, 1. , 1.5, 2. , 2.5, 3. ])
```

How can I apply rolling window function in order to get the most FREQUENT value per each `window` batch instead of median?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use [`scipy.stats.mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) alongwith `apply()` -

```
In [57]: a
Out[57]: 
0    2
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    7
5    3
6    2
7    4
8    6
9    3
dtype: int64

In [58]: from scipy import stats

In [59]: modeval = lambda x : mode(x)[0]

In [60]: a.rolling(window=5).apply(modeval).dropna()
Out[60]: 
4    2.0
5    2.0
6    2.0
7    2.0
8    2.0
9    3.0
dtype: float64
```